# Signalr, how to create JS function of sending private chat messages by email

Tags: c#

I need to implement private messages between users using Signalr, you need to enter the Email user to whom to send messages and the text of the message itself, need help in implementing the JS function of sending messages by email, here is my hub class :

```
namespace Example.Web.SignalR_Hubs
```

{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        static List     ConnectedUsers = new List();

```
    static List <MessageDetail> CurrentMessage = new List<MessageDetail>();



    public void onConnect(string userName)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;

        if (ConnectedUsers.Count(x => x.ConnectionId == id) == 0)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Add(new UserDetail { ConnectionId = id, UserName = userName });

            // send to caller
            Clients.Caller.OnConnected(id, userName, ConnectedUsers, CurrentMessage);



        }
    }


    public void SendMessageToAll(string userName, string message)
    {
        // store last 100 messages in cache
        AddMessageinCache(userName, message);

        // Broad cast message
        Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message);
    }



    public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)
    {
        string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;

        var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId);

        var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);

        if (toUser != null && fromUser != null)
        {

            Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);
            // send to caller
            Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUser, fromUser.UserName,message);

        }

    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Remove(item);

            var id = Context.ConnectionId;

            Clients.All.OnUserDisconnected(id, item.UserName);
        }
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    private void AddMessageinCache(string userName, string message)
    {
        CurrentMessage.Add(new MessageDetail { UserName = userName, Message = message });

        if (CurrentMessage.Count > 100)
            CurrentMessage.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why not have a look at the many available [code examples](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/signalr-chat-app-with-asp-net-webform-and-bootstrap/)?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
    var yourHubProxy= $.connection.chatHub;
    yourHubProxy.client.sendPrivateMessage= function (name, message) {
           // Do something if you receive private message (from  Clients.Client(toUserId).sendPrivateMessage(...) or  Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(...)
    };
    yourHubProxy.client.messageReceived= function (name, message) {
           // Do something if you receive other message from sever (from  Clients.All.messageReceived(userName, message);)
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // Wire up SendMessageToAllButton to call method on the server.
        $('#SendMessageToAll').click(function () {
             yourHubProxy.server.sendMessageToAll($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
             $('#message').val('').focus();
         });
        // Wire up SendMessageToPrivateto call method on the server.
        $('#SendMessageToPrivate').click(function () {
             contosoChatHubProxy.server.sendMessageToPrivate($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
             $('#message').val('').focus();
         });
    });
```

For more detail information you should read the docs there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client